# Software for maintaining arbitrary file collection across multiple volumes

Tags: software-recommendation, media-manager

I would like to use a single piece of software to maintain a collection of files. These files include music, movies, ebooks, win32 installers, photos and artwork. They are stored on my local HDD, remote HDD, CDs and DVDs.

By maintain, I mean I want to be able to browse the entire collection on my desktop without having a live remote connection or mounted volume. Thumbnails for each item would be ideal.

I don't mind having to shoehorn another application to suit this purpose. For example, I could imagine maintaining a collection of images using Shotwell, where each image represents a particular file (for example, the CD cover, movie poster, DVD cover, book cover, software cover or screenshot, thumbnail). Each image would be titled and tagged appropriately ("Sita Sings The Blues", "animated, creative-commons, movie, unwatched"). But then I need to easily and accurately store the file location ("/media/animated2/Sita Sings The Blues.mkv").

Any suggestions on an application or process? A cross-platform (Ubuntu + Win32) application that could access the same storage resource would be best.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the Tellico.

> :~$ apt-cache show tellico
>
> Description: collection manager for books,
>   videos, music
>
> Tellico is a collection manager for KDE. It includes
>   default collections for  books, bibliographies, comic books, videos,
>   music, coins, stamps, trading  cards, and wines, and also allows
>   custom collections; with unlimited  user-defined fields allowed.
>   Automatically formatted names, sorting by any  property, filters,
>   automatic ISBN validation and full customization for  printing or
>   display through XSLT files are some of the features present. It  can
>   import CSV, RIS, BibTeX, and BibTeXML files; and export CSV, HTML,
>   BibTeX,  BibTeXML, and PilotDB. Tellico can also import data from
>   Amazon, IMDb, CDDB,  or any US-MARC compliant z39.50 server.  .  The
>   files are stored in XML format, avoiding the need for database server.
>   It also makes it easy for other softwares to use the Tellico data.
>
> Homepage: http://tellico-project.org/